# PHP image load function reads from the controller instead of domain/folder/to/image

Tags: php

Dear stackoverflow community,

Loading images from function works when I am in the indexAction (index of the controller, e.g gallery). When I want to load images from function while in a sublink of the main controller (e.g gallery/family) it doesn't load the images.

So when going to: domain.com/gallery everything is working.
When going to domain.com/gallery/family the images will be trying to find "domain.com/gallery/app/assets/image/gallery/family/" instead of "domain.com/app/assets/image/gallery/family/".

Image location is at "app/assets/image/gallery/family/" then running this function:

```
public function insertFamilyImages()
  {
    $directory = 'app/assets/image/gallery/family/';
    $extension = '.jpg';

    $html = '';
    if ( file_exists($directory) ) {
       foreach ( glob($directory . '*' . $extension) as $file ) {
         $html .= '<li>';
         $html .= '<img src="' . $file . '" alt="">';
         $html .= '</li>';
       }
    } else {
       echo 'directory ' . $directory . ' doesn\'t exist!';
    }
    return $html;
  }
```

I am stuck at this and google doesn't help me. Neither I can find a similiar post on stackoverflow regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Caleb

Comment: Thank you Jay, if you have read my reply towards Dom I was not able to test the answer he gave right away as I work in a place where I cannot program and not even have a phone with me. I am glad I could check here to see if there were any answers. I will test it tonight and tell if the answer which was provided solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at this it looks like when you create your html you point the img src to the file system path and not the uri. This html will be loaded in a remote browser and the browser can't access a remote file system. It needs an uri.

E.g.
Let say your domain name is example.com and en example image is called eg.png
Your image is located on your disk at app/assets/image/gallery/family/eg.png (relative).
However your images are accessible externally at https://example.com/gallery/family/eg.png.

You code would look something like this:

```
public function insertFamilyImages()
  {
    $directory = 'app/assets/image/gallery/family/';
    $uri = 'https://example.com/gallery/family/';
    $extension = '.jpg';

    $html = '';
    if ( file_exists($directory) ) {
       foreach ( glob($directory . '*' . $extension) as $file ) {
         $file = $uri.basename($file);
         $html .= '<li>';
         $html .= '<img src="' . $file . '" alt="">';
         $html .= '</li>';
       }
    } else {
       echo 'directory ' . $directory . ' doesn\'t exist!';
    }
    return $html;
  }
```

You'll have to adjust this code to fit your case, but it should point you in the right direction where the problem lies. I used a complete uri here to point to the image to illustrate the point, but this could be made relative as well to the web root.

Comment: Thankyou very much for this answer. It does make a lot of sense to me! When I get back from work I will directly give it a try and see if it works. What happens is exactly what you describe. Once I get it working properly it doesn't show the image because its getting "hosted" somewhere else and not giving an error on the website itself. Will come back to it later today.

Comment: I cannot upvote this reply... Could someone for me? It seems I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: This gave me a good push into the right direction! And actually got it working, not yet how I want it to be. But you provided me with a good push into the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never load / read / import any file with relative path. Otherwise your code will be faulty unpredictable.

Always use absolute path. In first php file like index.php which is entry point to your application define global root path like this:

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__);
```

then use ROOT as your constant at all files access/manipulation in your application.

```
$directory = ROOT.'/app/assets/image/gallery/family/';
```

You will never have problems with paths.

Comment: Hello dear step, I did try'd to do this using define ROOT path. Since it didn't work I approached it the most easy way to accomplish. This doesn't solve the issue.